# Change selected row formatting in a sharepoint online list using JSON

Tags: json, formatting, row, sharepoint-online

In sharepoint online, I want to change the color and bold the text in the selected row item in a list view.  Can this be done using JSON?

Comment: Is there any way to do this?  Conditional formatting?

Comment: If I can shade alternate rows with view formatting in json wouldn't I be able to use the "additionalRowClass" and use an if statement for selected rows then set the formatting?  I just don't know how to grab the selected row's ID.